# Show that a function has a continuous derivative in $[a,b]$, then it can be written as a sum of monotone functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ where $g$ is non decreasing and $h$ is non increasing. I realise that we will need to construct these such that:
$$g'(x) = f'(x)\quad\text{and}\quad  h'(x) = 0\qquad\text{if}\quad  f'(x)\ge0.$$
And also $$g'(x)=0\quad\text{and}\quad h'(x)=f'(x)\qquad\text{if}\quad f'(x)<0$$
This is okay if $f'(x)$ has finitely many zeroes but I am unable to understand how to show that $g'(x)$ and $h'(x)$ are integrable in case $f$ has infinite zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given that $f'$ is continuos. Then $\max\{f'(x),0\}$ and $\min\{f'(x),0\}$ are also continuous, hence integrable.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much.